# rsync remove old backup on remote PC

Tags: 12.04, server, backup, rsync

Good day

I use this script to backup my home PC to remote PC

```
#!/bin/bash
#Todays date in ISO-8601 format: 
DAY0=`date -I`

#Yesterdays date in ISO-8601 format: 
DAY1=`date -I -d "1 day ago"`

#The source directory: 
SRC="/home/honza/Downloads/"

#The target directory: 
TRG="honza@192.168.80.197:/media/zaloha/$DAY0"

#The link destination directory: 
LNK="honza@192.168.80.195:/media/zaloha/$DAY1"

#The rsync options: 
OPT="-avh --delete --link-dest=$LNK

#Execute the backup 
rsync $OPT $SRC $TRG

#3 days ago in ISO-8601 format 
DAY3=`date -I -d "3 days ago"`

#Delete the backup from 3 days ago, if it exists 
if [ -d /honza@192.168.80.197:/media/zaloha/$DAY3 ] 
then rm -R /honza@192.168.80.197:/media/zaloha/$DAY3 
fi
```

I dont't know how to delete old backup than 3 days. Script works well when I backup on the same PC but not on a remote.

```
--link-dest arg does not exist: /honza@192.168.80.195:/media/zaloha/2013-03-15
```

and old backups are not deleted.

It also works well when a script is running on the remote PC. A SRC is

```
SRC = "honza@192.168.80.197:/home/hunts/Downloads"
```

But I do not know if it is the management solution?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't think, that this delete-command will work.
Maybe try to use a direct SSH-Command to delete the file, like:

`ssh honza@192.168.80.197 rm -rf /media/zaloha/$DAY3`

Sorry, but I can't tell you why the "link-dest"-Argument is not working.